# About integer constants in the book "C: A reference manual"

Tags: c, integer, hex, decimal, octal

In section 2.7.1 Integer constants, it says:

> To illustrate some of the subtleties of integer constants, assume that
>   type int uses a 16-bit twos-complement representation, type long uses
>   a 32-bit twos-complement representation, and type long long uses a
>   64-bit twos-complement representation. We list in Table 2-6 some
>   interesting integer constants...
>
> An interesting point to note from this table is that integers in the
>   range 2^15 through 2^16 - 1 will have positive values when written as
>   decimal constants but negative values when written as octal or
>   hexadecimal constants (and cast to type int).

But, as far as I know, integers in the range 2^15 - 2^16-1 written as hex/octal constants also have positive values when cast to type `unsigned`. Is the book wrong?

Comment: I believe it's talking about signed literals, which would exhibit the described behavior.

Comment: But when the 16-bit signed int can't hold the constants written as octal/hex, the constants will be cast to unsigned int.

Comment: 0x8000 would be sign-extended to 32 bits: 0xFFFF8000.  But 32768 (which is 0x8000) would be regarded as already larger than what will fit in 16 bits and hence would be zero-padded.

Comment: 0x8000 (the literal) is a positive number, it is never sign-extended

Comment: The way you said "and cast to type unsigned" is a bit strange ... "cast" is something that you do by writing `(int)` or `(unsigned int)`, it's not something that just happens.

Comment: it's called "extended", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the described setup, decimal literals in the range [32768,65535] have type `long int`, and hexadecimal literals in that range have type `unsigned int`.

So, the constant `0xFFFF` is an `unsigned int` with value 65535, and the constant `65535` is a signed `long int` with value 65535.

I think your text is trying to discuss the cases:

```
(int)0xFFFF
(int)65535
```

Now, since `int` cannot represent the value `65535` both of these cause *out-of-range conversion* which is *implementation-defined* (or may raise an implementation-defined signal).

Most commonly (in fact, all 2's complement systems I've ever heard of), it will use a combination of truncation and reinterpretation in both of those cases, giving a value of `-1`.

So the last paragraph of your quote is a bit strange. `65535` and `0xFFFF` are both large positive numbers; `(int)0xFFFF` and `(int)65535` are (probably) both negative numbers;  but if you cast one and don't cast the other then you get a discrepancy which is not surprising.

Comment: AFAIK, integer literals *used to be* like that in old (probably pre C99) standards.

Comment: @EOF the ideas are the same now as they were, except that `long long` was added in C99.  So in C90 with 32-bit ints, `4294967295` would be `unsigned int` because there is simply no larger type for it to be; but in C99 it is signed `long long` .

Comment: @MattMcNabb so what the book is talking about? It makes me confused.

Comment: @noinput I think it's trying to point out that `0xFFFF` and `65535` have different types (but the "interesting thing" is not particularly interesting)